# loop through array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
name: {
        "accounts"=>{
          "data"=>[

              {
              "access_token"=>"CAAUCR7n0ZC50BAGmqTb3FEYz9FzZCZAZBFdVZC6AM3iQrGUsVqWvCfI5q5vh4seRH6LwIQTSkZAznzeBaPlZBjQ3zcwdfWxPBIr78FZBVa8pymUzVX0UESSS7QC0Dm7iIUCMyRH175HV6ZCa2ugBmbJNB7joZB7oiILPH5jtpcCLkg8e7ztxyjeSODSO4ZBAM9z1pkZD",
              "name"=>"UNX",
              "id"=>"387832931391777",
              },
              {
              "access_token"=>"CAAUCR7n0ZC50BAEYnXR7bWGvhktsGXCaB43vB0mhSuKgZBQG1m5FyovssyVKt0XYv7K7essxPkVPU3nQZCqrQJeTtWhApV1cSYGsb4JbNmYlUiHmLHueEBjuomqRWVX6tvMZA0dA5zqMApbmPUtA7SBqruWUFzZAwZC9xZBXFMZCZAW7WNEL7epkb9dmiL2pX3AoZD",
              "name"=>"Fuitter",
              "id"=>"1412081982453898",
              }
              ]}}
```

I am trying to get the `name` key from the `data` array of hashes. I have used `each` to loop but that way I had to nest loop inside of loop. Is there another way to make this work?

This `name` key is actually column in my database of data type json.

```
<% session[:user].account.name.each do |test| %>
  <% test.each do |me| %>
    <%= me['data']['name']%> #unable to fetch name and gives me undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass error 
    <br>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I am trying to get the value by nesting loops, but I got this error

```
unable to fetch name and gives me undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass error
```

Comment: I saw your json example and I think this code should be.

`<% session[:user].name.accounts.each do |test| %>
<%test['data'].each do |me| %>
<%= me['name']%>
<%end%>
<%end%>`

Comment: Do you mean you want the values of the keys `"name"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
data_hash = { name: {
        "accounts"=>{
          "data"=>[

              {
              "access_token"=>"CAAUCR7n0ZC50BAGmqTb3FEYz9FzZCZAZBFdVZC6AM3iQrGUsVqWvCfI5q5vh4seRH6LwIQTSkZAznzeBaPlZBjQ3zcwdfWxPBIr78FZBVa8pymUzVX0UESSS7QC0Dm7iIUCMyRH175HV6ZCa2ugBmbJNB7joZB7oiILPH5jtpcCLkg8e7ztxyjeSODSO4ZBAM9z1pkZD",
              "name"=>"UNX",
              "id"=>"387832931391777",
              },
              {
              "access_token"=>"CAAUCR7n0ZC50BAEYnXR7bWGvhktsGXCaB43vB0mhSuKgZBQG1m5FyovssyVKt0XYv7K7essxPkVPU3nQZCqrQJeTtWhApV1cSYGsb4JbNmYlUiHmLHueEBjuomqRWVX6tvMZA0dA5zqMApbmPUtA7SBqruWUFzZAwZC9xZBXFMZCZAW7WNEL7epkb9dmiL2pX3AoZD",
              "name"=>"Fuitter",
              "id"=>"1412081982453898",
              }
              ]
          }
        }
      }

data_hash[:name]['accounts']['data'].map { |d| puts d['name'] }
    # => UNX
    # => Fuitter
```

Comment: Raj Shakya, please consider upvoting the answer too if it really helped you solve your problem. Thanks.